# Position an element behind a text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have got a horizontal bar with links like this:

```
<div class="blackbar">
    <span class="blackbar-text"><a href="news.php">NEWS</a></span>
    <span class="blackbar-text"><a href="foo.php">FOO</a></span>
    <span class="blackbar-text"><a href="bar.php">BAR</a></span>
</div>
```

with this css:

```
div.blackbar {
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #888;
}
.blackbar-text {
    padding: 0px 12px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}
.blackbar-text a:link,.blackbar-text a:visited {
    color:#e8e8e8;
}
```

Now when you mouseover one of those spans a layer should appear behind the text but above the blackbar-div. it should also be possible to extend the borders of the blackbar-div, because it should be like a dropdown element containing submenus.

I can easily handle the mouseover/out part with jquery, but how do I put up the HTML and CSS to get the effect?

here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o4su1Lbd/

basically, the #teams div should move between the text and the background of the bar like so:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please provide us with a fiddle link.

Comment: @krishna_tandon would this be enough? https://jsfiddle.net/o4su1Lbd/

Comment: The fiddle is fine. Just want to know a little more about the final UI you are expecting. Slightly confused with the statement.
::hover in css maybe the solution for your query. If you can provide the final screenshot of what you want, it will be little easy to proceed further.

Comment: Also, what kind of layer you are expecting. Provide those details too.

You can add the jquery code also in fiddle. and what you desire from css

Comment: @krishna_tandon i have edited the fiddle and provided a rudimentary screenshot. as for the layer kind, i dont really care. i just thought div is the way to go.

Comment: **You are required to post your markup and code here, not a jsfiddle.**  [mcve] A fiddle can compliment your example but not be used in its stead. @krishna_tandon

Comment: If you want to create submenu, being able to 'extend' the borders will not be of any help. You need to create new list of items, hide them with opacity:0, or display: none, and then make them appear on mouseover. You can then add to parent link z-index with height z value, which will put it on top of, as you have on image

Answer (score 1):

You should change all the spans to divs and set .blackbar-text to display: inline-block; so they line up. Then add a div with nested links under one of the .blackbar-text divs

```
  <div class="blackbar-text dropdown">
    <a href="bar.php">BAR</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Position .dropdown-content absolute and set the display to none. And then the dropdown magic happens here. With the :hover psuedo-class applied to .dropdown .dropdown-content display: block, this with have the hover over effect you are looking for.

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is a link to my solution. https://jsfiddle.net/tophermurphy/o4su1Lbd/19/

Comment: thanks, it seems this pretty much achieves the same effect as your other answer.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Icon Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script>
$('#cssmenu').prepend('<div id="menu-button">Menu</div>');
$('#cssmenu #menu-button').on('click', function(){
  var menu = $(this).next('ul');
  if (menu.hasClass('open')) {
    menu.removeClass('open');
  } else {
    menu.addClass('open');
  }
});
</script>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-newspaper-o"></i> NEWS</span></a></li>
     <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i> FOO</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Sub link 1</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Sub link 2</span></a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span>Sub link 3</span></a></li>
           <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Sub link 4</span></a>
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Sub link 4.1</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Sub link 4.2</span></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#"><span>Sub link 4.3</span></a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-ellipsis-h"></i> BAR</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700);
#cssmenu {
  background: #4cb6ea;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu ul:after,
#cssmenu:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .2s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: auto;
  z-index: 999;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li {
  max-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
  background: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 13px;
  right: 15px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li.has-sub:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 15px;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 15px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #000;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 170px;
  padding: 11px 10px 11px 20px;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul li ul li.active > a {
  color: #4cb6ea;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover:after,
#cssmenu ul li ul li.active:after {
  background: #4cb6ea;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul > li {
  max-height: 72px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li:hover > ul {
  right: 100%;
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li a {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: height .2s;
  -moz-transition: height .2s;
  -ms-transition: height .2s;
  -o-transition: height .2s;
  transition: height .2s;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 40px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  background: #fff;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  top: 16px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #4cb6ea;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: 21px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active:after {
  height: 100%;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:after {
  background: #000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a:before,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a:before {
  border-top-color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul > li {
  max-height: 72px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
  width: 170px;
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li {
  width: 170px;
  display: block;
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu > ul {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
    transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-right ul li a {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li a {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul li a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul.open {
    max-height: 1000px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.25);
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul > li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul > li:after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:before,
  #cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:after,
  #cssmenu ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul,
  #cssmenu ul li ul li ul,
  #cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul li ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul li ul li:hover > ul {
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    right: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul li,
  #cssmenu ul li:hover > ul > li {
    max-height: 999px;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul li a {
    padding: 8px 20px 8px 35px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul ul li a {
    padding: 8px 20px 8px 50px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li ul li:hover > a {
    color: #000;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    right: 20px;
    top: 16px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    right: 20px;
    top: 26px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
  }
}
```

On desktop:

[image]

On smartphoe:

[image]

> For colors you can change them to fit your requirement

Answer (score -1):

You don't want to use span classes and javascript is unnecessary. You want to set the nested contend to display:none and then use the pseudo-class :hover to display block. To show the element. Here is an example
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar

Comment: And there is the downvote. OP is interested in help.

Comment: just to clarify: that downvote was not from me (OP). infact i am trying your approach now and will let you know soon if it works out for me.

Comment: Ok. Someone else is trolling.

Comment: ok, it works for me and it's almost as i imagined it, except that the dropdown-content is just below the bar and not between the bar and the text. but i guess i can achieve that with some extra css.

Comment: Set .dropdown to position: relative and then with .dropdown-content set to position: absolute so can position the dropdown content relative to the parent container using top: and left: in the css.

Comment: Ok. I think I get what you were going for. More of a mobile menu. remove .dropdown position:relative and add position: relative to .blackbar. This will set the absolute positioning to that container. Set .dropdown-content width:100% and left: 0px; then .dropdown-content a, to text-align:center and I think that will get you on your way.

Comment: I updated the fiddle to match what i just commented https://jsfiddle.net/tophermurphy/bupty4xv/